# How to fetch SHA_256 value from manifest.json file in JFROG

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray, jjaql

I am trying to fetch the SHA_256 value from manifest.json file but unable to get using aql.

Below is the cmd I am using:

```
ubuntu@test:~$ **curl -sS -u sumkumar:$pw -XPOST -k  -H "Content-type: text/plain" https://<URL>/artifactory/api/search/aql  -d 'items.find({"repo":"xyz"},{"path":"a/b/c"}).include("*")'**
```

```html
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "xyz",
  "path" : "a/b/c",
  "name" : "manifest.json",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 1579,
  "created" : "2018-03-13T11:58:33.771Z",
  "created_by" : "uex-sp-cd",
  "modified" : "2018-03-15T14:17:38.299Z",
  "modified_by" : "uex-sp-cd",
  "updated" : "2018-03-15T14:17:38.299Z",
  "depth" : 4,
  "actual_md5" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "actual_sha1" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "original_md5" : "NO_ORIG",
  "original_sha1" : "NO_ORIG",
  "virtual_repos" : [ ]
},{
```

However, if you look the original manifest.json file from UI.It contains SHA256 value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kheuK.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AQL documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-EntitiesandFields), the `item` entity has the `sha256` field. But it mentions the following note:

> SHA-256 is supported from Artifactory version 5.5
>
> You can only do an AQL search on an Artifact that has been deployed to Artifactory version 5.5 or above, or if you have [migrated your database](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Checksum-Based+Storage#ChecksumBasedStorage-BasedStorage-MigratingtheDatabasetoIncludeSHA-256) as described in [SHA-256 Support](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Checksum-Based+Storage#ChecksumBasedStorage-BasedStorage-SHA-256Support) after upgrading Artifactory to version 5.5 and above.

Please verify your Artifactory fits the requirements above.

In addition, assuming this is a Docker `manifest.json`, it specifically should also have the SHA256 in a property named `docker.manifest.digest` (and maybe also a property named `sha256`). To get the property values you can add `"property.*"` to the `include(..)` part of the query.

For example:

```
items.find({"repo":"xyz","path":"a/b/c","name":"manifest.json"})
     .include("repo","path","name","sha256","property.*")
```

Will return something like:

```json
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "xyz",
  "path" : "a/b/c",
  "name" : "manifest.json",
  "sha256" : "34cb6f8e1e1aca...",
  "properties" : [ {
    "key" : "docker.manifest.digest",
    "value" : "sha256:34cb6f8e1e1aca..."
  },{
    "key" : "sha256",
    "value" : "34cb6f8e1e1aca..."
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I am running the artifactory version 7.17.4 rev.                                                     yes the docker manifest file contains the sha-256 but while running the above cmd ...sha256 is not getting listed.I have attached the image above when you click on enter image description and yes this is docker image

Comment: Edited my answer to add an example.